# ios - dynamically create and display unicode strings

Tags: ios, string, unicode, hex, decimal

I have a `UILabel` in which I want to display a Unicode character. The following works:

```
label.text = @"\U000025A0";
```

Now I want to dynamically generate the Unicode character from a decimal number as follows:

```
label.text = NSString stringWithFormat:@"\U%08x",9632];
```

Xcode compiler fails with the following error:

```
\U used with no following hex digits
```

Is there a way to convert the decimal number 9632 to Unicode and then display it in a `UILabel`?

Comment: Use `+ [NSString stringWithCharacters:length:]`. Don't forget about f'ing surrogate pairs which `NSString`, miserably and unacceptably, fails to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a same issue to display entypo Font special character, so I implemented my own `EntypoStringCreator` class (with some help from SO). Here are the method used to convert a unicode number to a nsstring:

.h

```
@interface EntypoStringCreator : NSObject

+(NSString *)stringForIcon:(UTF32Char)char32;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation EntypoStringCreator


+(NSString *)stringForIcon:(UTF32Char)char32
{
    if ((char32 & 0xFFFF0000) != 0)
        return [self stringFromUTF32Char:char32];
    else
        return [self stringFromUTF16Char:(UTF16Char)(char32&0xFFFF)];
}

+(NSString *)stringFromUTF32Char:(UTF32Char)char32
{
    char32 -= 0x10000;
    unichar highSurrogate = (unichar)(char32 >> 10); // leave the top 10 bits
    highSurrogate += 0xD800;
    unichar lowSurrogate = char32 & 0x3FF; // leave the low 10 bits
    lowSurrogate += 0xDC00;
    return [NSString stringWithCharacters:(unichar[]){highSurrogate, lowSurrogate} length:2];
}

+(NSString *)stringFromUTF16Char:(UTF16Char)char16
{
    return [NSString stringWithCharacters:(unichar[]){char16} length:1];
}


@end
```

Answer (score -1):

try this ::

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"0xF09F948A"]; <-- UTF-8 Hexadecimal Encoding

myLabel.text = myString;
```

Comment: this does not answer the question. **think.**