# How to convert surrogate pair to Unicode scalar in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, scalar, surrogate-pairs

The following example is taken from the [Strings and Characters documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html):

[image]

The values `55357` (`U+D83D` in hex) and `56374` (`U+DC36` in hex) are the surrogate pairs that form the Unicode scalar `U+1F436`, which is the `DOG FACE` character. Is there any way to go the other direction? That is, can I convert a surrogate pair into a scalar?

I tried

```
let myChar: Character = "\u{D83D}\u{DC36}"
```

but I got an "Invalid Unicode scalar" error.

[This Objective C answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24913637/3681880) and [this project](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftySurrogate) seem to be custom solutions, but is there anything built into Swift (especially Swift 2.0+) that does this?

Comment: Specify the code point directly: `\u{1F436}`. There is an example in the document you link to `let sparklingHeart = "\u{1F496}" // , Unicode scalar U+1F496`

Comment: What if I don't know the full code point? That is, what if I only know the surrogate pairs?

Comment: `String` has a `init?(_ utf16: String.UTF16View)` method, but I haven't found yet how to *create* a `String.UTF16View` from a given array. – A similar question (with possible solutions) is here: [Is there a way to create a String from utf16 array in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542170/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-string-from-utf16-array-in-swift).

Comment: @MartinR oops sorry see you’ve already given the utf16 decoding answer. Though you might also find the 2.0 version interesting.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity: The code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/24757284/1187415 works for Swift 2 as well. It is a bit longer because it distinguishes between "end of input" and "error" condition.

Comment: @Suragch You seem to be asking how to calculate the code point based on a surrogate pair. I’ve answered that here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/31287075](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31287075/96656)

Answer (score 6):

There are formulas to calculate the original code point based on a surrogate pair and vice versa. From https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding#surrogate-formulae:

> [Section 3.7 of The Unicode Standard
>   3.0](http://unicode.org/versions/Unicode3.0.0/ch03.pdf) defines the algorithms for converting to and from surrogate pairs.
>
> A code point `C` greater than `0xFFFF` corresponds to a surrogate pair
>   `<H, L>` as per the following formula:
>
> ```
> H = Math.floor((C - 0x10000) / 0x400) + 0xD800
> L = (C - 0x10000) % 0x400 + 0xDC00
> ```
>
> The reverse mapping, i.e. from a surrogate pair `<H, L>` to a Unicode
>   code point `C`, is given by:
>
> ```
> C = (H - 0xD800) * 0x400 + L - 0xDC00 + 0x10000
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Given an sequence of UTF-16 code units (i.e. 16-bit numbers, such as you get from `String.utf16` or just an array of numbers), you can use the `UTF16` type and its `decode` method to turn it into `UnicodeScalars`, which you can then convert into a `String`.

It’s a bit of a grungy item, that takes a generator (as it does stateful processing) and returns an enum that indicates a result (with an associated type of the scalar), or an error or completion.  Swift 2.0 pattern matching makes it a lot easier to use:

```
let u16data: [UInt16] = [0xD83D,0xDC36]
//or let u16data = "Hello, ".utf16

var g = u16data.generate()
var s: String = ""
var utf16 = UTF16()
while case let .Result(scalar) = utf16.decode(&g) {
    print(scalar, &s)
}
print(s) // prints
```

Comment: It took me a little while to learn some of the new concepts (1. [decode method](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_UTF16_Structure/index.html), 2. generator ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)) and [here](http://devsmash.com/blog/whats-the-big-deal-with-generators)), 3. [stateful](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/154499/186547)), but this was a useful answer. I guess the answer to my original question is no, there is nothing built in to Swift to do this directly, but it is not too hard to generate.