# Validate Unicode code point in Swift

Tags: swift, unicode

I'm writing a routine in Swift that needs to try to convert an arbitrary integer to a UnicodeScalar or return an error.  The constructor `UnicodeScalar(_:Int)` does the job for valid code points, but it crashes when passed integers that are not valid code points.

Is there a Swift (or Foundation) function I can call to pre-flight that an integer `i` is a valid Unicode code point and won't cause `UnicodeScalar(i)` to crash?

Answer (score 3):

**Update for Swift 3:**

`UnicodeScalar` has a failable initializer now which verifies if the
given number is a valid Unicode code point or not:

```
if let unicode = UnicodeScalar(0xD800) {
    print(unicode)
} else {
    print("invalid")
}
```

---

*(Previous answer:)* You can use the built-in `UTF32()` codec to check if a given integer
is a valid Unicode scalar:

```
extension UnicodeScalar {
    init?(code: UInt32) {
        var codegen = GeneratorOfOne(code) // As suggested by @rintaro
        var utf32 = UTF32()
        guard case let .Result(scalar) = utf32.decode(&codegen) else {
            return nil
        }
        self = scalar
    }
}
```

(Using ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24757284/1187415
and https://stackoverflow.com/a/31285671/1187415.)

Comment: `GeneratorOfOne(code)` is slightly better than `[code].generate()`

Answer (score 2):

The [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID293) states

> A Unicode scalar is any Unicode *code point* in the range U+0000 to
>   U+D7FF inclusive or U+E000 to U+10FFFF inclusive.

The UnicodeScalar constructor does not crash for all values in those ranges in Swift 2.0b4.  I use this convenience constructor:

```
extension UnicodeScalar {
    init?(code: Int) {
        guard (code >= 0 && code <= 0xD7FF) || (code >= 0xE000 && code <= 0x10FFFF) else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(code)
    }
}
```

Comment: Good question and solution! For the sake of completeness, I have provided an alternative answer.

Comment: That feature is now "built-in" with Swift 3, see below.