# Print unicode character from variable (swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, unicode

I have a problem I couldn't find a solution to.
I have a string variable holding the unicode "1f44d" and I want to convert it to a unicode character .

Usually one would do something like this:

```
println("\u{1f44d}") //
```

Here is what I mean:

```
let charAsString = "1f44d" // code in variable
println("\u{\(charAsString)}") // not working
```

I have tried several other ways but somehow the workings behind this magic stay hidden for me.

One should imagine the value of charAsString coming from an API call or from another object.

Comment: 7 year later and still Apple didn't fix this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be done in two steps:

1. convert `charAsString` to `Int` code
2. convert code to unicode character

Second step can be done e.g. like this

```
var code = 0x1f44d
var scalar = UnicodeScalar(code)
var string = "\(scalar)"
```

As for first the step, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189338/swift-native-functions-to-have-numbers-as-hex-strings) how to convert `String` in hex representation to `Int`

Comment: Short version of converting a hex string like "1f44d" to an Int:
`Int(strtoul(charAsString, nil, 16))`

Comment: This worked well for me; I did convert vars to lets and used a guard on the scalar step to avoid it printing an optional.

Answer (score 14):

One possible solution (explanations "inline"):

```
let charAsString = "1f44d"

// Convert hex string to numeric value first:
var charCode : UInt32 = 0
let scanner = NSScanner(string: charAsString)
if scanner.scanHexInt(&charCode) {

    // Create string from Unicode code point:
    let str = String(UnicodeScalar(charCode))
    println(str) // 
} else {
    println("invalid input")
}
```

Slightly simpler with **Swift 2:**

```
let charAsString = "1f44d"

// Convert hex string to numeric value first:
if let charCode = UInt32(charAsString, radix: 16) {
    // Create string from Unicode code point:
    let str = String(UnicodeScalar(charCode))
    print(str) // 
} else {
    print("invalid input")
}
```

Note also that not all code points are valid Unicode scalars,
compare [Validate Unicode code point in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693419/validate-unicode-code-point-in-swift).

---

Update for **Swift 3:**

```
public init?(_ v: UInt32)
```

is now a failable initializer of `UnicodeScalar` and checks if the
given numeric input is a valid Unicode scalar value:

```
let charAsString = "1f44d"

// Convert hex string to numeric value first:
if let charCode = UInt32(charAsString, radix: 16),
    let unicode = UnicodeScalar(charCode) {
    // Create string from Unicode code point:
    let str = String(unicode)
    print(str) // 
} else {
    print("invalid input")
}
```

Comment: Reusing another user answer to improve your own answer just seemed to me like an awful way to do things here… But I might be wrong maybe it's something usual.

Comment: @Fantattitude: Believe me or not, but I did not see your answer before I edited this answer using code from **my own** previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27190430/1187415.

Comment: I do believe you don't worry just found it a bit harsh. I'm beginning participating after years of only reading so I may make mistakes. Still you could improve your answer by getting rid of the radix (the default value seems to work fine here).

Comment: @Fantattitude: No, it does not, your code actually crashes if I try it.

Comment: @MartinR Oh well playground fooled me, didn't update after I removed it.

Comment: May I suggest using Int with radix and printing the UnicodeScalar directly (without using a String) ? It's shorter and gives every hints needed to answer the question I think. (+ looks less like black magic to some people not understanding all the Int types)

Comment: @Fantattitude: `UInt32` is the underlying value type of `UnicodeScalar`, so using the `init(_ v: UInt32)` constructor seems more natural to me. It is correct that there is also a `init(_ v: Int)` constructor (defined in an extension of UnicodeScalar), but I see no advantage using it. As an example `let i = -1 ; let u = UnicodeScalar(i)` compiles, but crashes at runtime. – I also prefer the explicit constructor `String(...)` here instead of string interpolation `"\(uScalar)"` (which does black magic as well :).

Comment: I knew you'd say this about the underlying type :P. You can also print(uScalar) without going through String interpolation, or is it doing it behind when type isn't supported? Looks more like UnicodeScalar is CustomStringConvertible to me but can't check for now.

Comment: @HemangPandya: I have rejected your edit suggestion because the code is (to the best of by knowledge) still correct. Please let me know if there is a problem with it!

Answer (score 7):

As of Swift 2.0, every `Int` type has an initializer able to take `String` as an input. You can then easily generate an `UnicodeScalar` corresponding and print it afterwards. Without having to change your representation of chars as string ;).

**UPDATED: Swift 3.0 changed UnicodeScalar initializer**

```
print("\u{1f44d}") // 

let charAsString = "1f44d" // code in variable

let charAsInt = Int(charAsString, radix: 16)! // As indicated by @MartinR radix is required, default won't do it
let uScalar = UnicodeScalar(charAsInt)! // In Swift 3.0 this initializer is failible so you'll need either force unwrap or optionnal unwrapping

print("\(uScalar)")
```

Comment: Using Swift 3.0. Your answer does not print the desired result unless I also add the exclamation point to let uScalar = UnicodeScalar(charAsInt)!, otherwise what I see is Optional("\u{0001F44D}").

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
let char = "-12"
print(char.unicodeScalars.map {$0.value }))
```

You'll get the values as:

```
[45, 49, 50]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple ways to do it:

```
let string = "1f44d"
```

Solution 1:

```
"&#x\(string);".applyingTransform(.toXMLHex, reverse: true)
```

Solution 2:

```
"U+\(string)".applyingTransform(StringTransform("Hex/Unicode"), reverse: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

I made this extension that works pretty well:

```
extension String {
    var unicode: String? {
        if let charCode = UInt32(self, radix: 16),
           let unicode = UnicodeScalar(charCode) {
            let str = String(unicode)
            return str
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

How to test it:

```
if let test = "e9c8".unicode {
    print(test)
}
```

//print: [image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use string interpolation in Swift as you try to use it. Therefore, the following code won't compile:

```
let charAsString = "1f44d"
print("\u{\(charAsString)}")
```

You will have to convert your string variable into an integer (using [`init(_:radix:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2924481-init) initializer) then create a Unicode scalar from this integer. The Swift 5 Playground sample code below shows how to proceed:

```
let validCodeString = "1f44d"
let validUnicodeScalarValue = Int(validCodeString, radix: 16)!
let validUnicodeScalar = Unicode.Scalar(validUnicodeScalarValue)!
print(validUnicodeScalar) //
```