# String with Unicode (variable)

Tags: ios, swift, unicode

I would like to set some unicode strings (for a custom font icon).

Like:

```
cell.centerIconLabel.text = "\u{f013}"
```

But when i now read some variables from a webservice, how can i convert this to an unicode string?

If the webservice returns me "\u{f013}" and i set this as string, it will show only the string (and not the icon).

// not working

```
cell.centerIconLabel.text = item.icon // which contains "\u{f013}"
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Thanks Martin, that was the answer i was looking for. Maybe add as answer here too (was unable to find it on Stackoverflow).

```
let code = 0xf013
cell.centerIconLabel.text = String(UnicodeScalar(code))
```

Comment: How do you read the string from the web service? Why can the web service not send Unicode characters without escaping them with  `\u{}`? JSON for example supports arbitrary unicode characters.

Comment: But how can i set a variable then? How can i say Swift that this is a unicode string (otherwise it will display me f013.)

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are looking for: [Print unicode character from variable (swift)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696142/print-unicode-character-from-variable-swift).

Comment: use attribute text with this may fix issue