# How to print Unicode Characters in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, character-encoding

I want to print Unicode characters for some special symbol like `,',@,$ so please let me know if there is any method which converts string to unicode characters like \u00e2...

Thanks,

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696142/print-unicode-character-from-variable-swift

Comment: Is it your goal to access the characters of a string, or, given a string of unicode characters, to get their unicode descriptors, e.g. given `"â"` receive `"\u00e2"`?

Answer (score 1):

You can get your string unicodeScalars value, convert to hexa and finish padding it with leading zeros:

```
extension String {
    var unicodes: [String] {
        return unicodeScalars.map{ String($0.value, radix: 16) }
    }
    func paddingToLeft(maxLength: Int) -> String {
        return repeatElement("0", count: max(0,maxLength-count)) + self
    }
}
```

---

```
let str =  "\u{00e2}"
let hexa = str.unicodes.first!
print(hexa.paddingToLeft(maxLength: 4))  // "00e2\n"
```