# How to transform a string into a Unicode character

Tags: python, unicode

I would like to create a pretty simple code to get multiple string inputs and show as Unicode characters, let's say for example:

2119 01b4 2602 210c 00f8 1f24
(This should show 'Python' with some symbols)

But I keep getting the following exception:

**SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape**

I'm trying to use '\u' to keep it simple, but if there's no other way to do this, I wouldn't bother.

My code:

```
while True:
    string = input()
    print(f'\u{string}', end='')
```

I searched and found something in Swift which is exactly what I want to do in Python, but I didn't quite understand that: [Print unicode character from variable (swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696142/print-unicode-character-from-variable-swift).

Comment: Check out the `ord()` function.

Comment: `'\u0000'` is part of Python's literal syntax. You can't use substitutions to create syntax any more than you could run, say, `value = ''' ' + str(something) + ' '''`, and then expect `f'{value}'` to call `str(something)`; if it _did_ work, it would imply serious security bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you don't *really* care about whether the `\u` syntax is used, this would look like:

```
while True:
    string = input()
    print(chr(int(string, 16)), end='')
```

If you *do* in fact care for some reason:

```
while True:
    string = input()
    print((br'\u' + string.encode('utf-8')).decode('unicode_escape'), end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the unicode escape takes precedence over the f-string format specification. It sees `"\u{str"` as a 4 character escape sequence. You can split this in to two steps: create the escape and then decode. Since unicode characters can exceed 4 bytes, you may as well go large.

```
>>> import codecs
>>> string = "2119 01b4 2602 210c 00f8 1f24"
>>> for s in string.split(" "):
...     print(codecs.decode(rf"\U{s.zfill(8)}", "unicode-escape"), end="")
... 
ℙƴ☂ℌøἤ
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly construct `\uxxxx` escape sequences since that is a language construct, but it is more straightforward to use `chr` to convert Unicode ordinals to characters.  Also `int(s,16)` will convert a hexadecimal string to an integer:

```
>>> print(''.join(chr(int(x,16)) for x in input().split()))
2119 01b4 2602 210c 00f8 1f24
ℙƴ☂ℌøἤ
```